# Looping through items on a list in R

Tags: r, list, addition

this may be a simple question but I'm fairly new to R.
What I want to do is to perform some kind of addition on the indexes of a list, but once I get to a maximum value it goes back to the first value in that list and start over from there.

for example:

```
x <-2
data <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)

data[x]
1

data[x+12]
1

data[x+13]
3
```

or something functionaly equivalent. In the end i want to be able to do something like

```
v=6
x=8
y=9
z=12
values <- c(v,x,y,z)
data <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
set <- c(data[values[1]],data[values[2]], data[values[3]],data[values[4]])

set
5 7 8 11

values <- values + 8

set
1 3 4 7
```

I've tried some stuff with additon and substraction to the lenght of my list but it does not work well on the lower numbers.
I hope this was a clear enough explanation,

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need a loop here as `vector`s can take vectors of length >= 1 as index

```
data[values]
#[1]  5  7  8 11
```

NOTE: Both the objects are `vector`s and not `list`

If we need to reset the index

```
values <- values + 8
ifelse(values > length(data), values - length(data) - 1, values) 
#[1] 1 3 4 7
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and the correction!, it is working the way I needed it to.